# scala quirky in this while loop code

Tags: scala

Yesterday, this piece of code caused me a headache. I fixed it by reading the file line by line. Any ideas ?

The while loop never seems to get executed even though the no of lines in the file is greater than 1.

```
 val lines = Source.fromFile( new File("file.txt") ).getLines;

 println( "total lines:"+lines.size );

 var starti = 1;
 while( starti < lines.size ){
   val nexti = Math.min( starti + 10, lines.size  );

   println( "batch ("+starti+", "+nexti+") total:" + lines.size )
   val linesSub = lines.slice(starti, nexti)
   //do something with linesSub
   starti = nexti
 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is indeed tricky, and I would even say it's a bug in `Iterator`. `getLines` returns an `Iterator` which proceeds lazily. So what seems to happen is that if you ask for `lines.size` the iterator goes through the whole file to count the lines. Afterwards, it's "exhausted":

```
scala> val lines = io.Source.fromFile(new java.io.File("....txt")).getLines
lines: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator

scala> lines.size
res4: Int = 15

scala> lines.size
res5: Int = 0

scala> lines.hasNext
res6: Boolean = false
```

You see, when you execute `size` twice, the result is zero.

There are two solutions, either you force the iterator into something 'stable', like `lines.toSeq`. Or you forget about `size` and do the "normal" iteration:

```
while(lines.hasNext) {
  val linesSub = lines.take(10)
  println("batch:" + linesSub.size)
  // do something with linesSub
}
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the right way to do iteration with a while loop in Scala.

Comment: So why do you consider this to be a bug? Iterators usually don't know how many elements they contain. In Particular you can't find out the number of lines in a file without reading the entire file.

Comment: It depends on what one calls a bug. It behaves as the authors intended and is documented. But, the naming is not intuitive. I most definitely did not expect it to return an iterator. getLines does not imply an iterator to me in any way. I most definitely like this feature though.

Comment: I think `Iterator` should not have a `size` method. If you provide one, it should not have side effects, because most sane minds wouldn't expect them. At best, the method name should be different. Maybe `count()`?

Comment: I agree. count implies an active operation much more than size.

Comment: And there is a convention that parameterless methods which have a side effect should have empty parentheses (thus `count()` and not `count`)

Answer (score 5):

None of the above answers quite hits the nail on the head.

Theres a good reason why an `Iterator` is returned here. By being lazy, it takes pressure off the heap, and the String representing each line can then be garbage collected as soon as you've finished with it.  In the case of large files, this can make all the difference for avoiding an OutOfMemoryException.

Ideally, you'd work directly with the iterator and not force it into a strict collection type.

Using `grouped` then, as per om-nom-nom's answer:

```
for (linesSub <- lines grouped 10) {
  //do something with linesSub
}
```

And if you wanted to retain the `println` counter, zip in an index:

```
for ( (linesSub, batchIdx) <- (lines grouped 10).zipWithIndex ) {
  println("batch " + batchIdx)
  //do something with linesSub
}
```

If you *really* need the total, invoke `getLines` twice.  Once for the count, and a second time to actually process the lines.

Answer (score 4):

The second time you call lines.size it returns 0. This is because `lines` is an iterator, not an array.

Answer (score 4):

I've rewritten your code in a `Seq` way, that was proposed in @0__ answer:

```
val batchSize = 10;
val lines = Source.fromFile("file.txt").getLines.toSeq;

 println( "total lines:"+lines.length);

 var processed = 0;
 lines.grouped(batchSize).foreach( batch => {
      println( "batch ("+processed+","+(processed+Math.min(lines.length-processed,batchSize))+")
               total:"+lines.length
      );
      processed = processed + batchSize;
      //do something with batch
   }
 )
```